# Tkinter: displaying label with automatically updated variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label, updates

I know there are a lot of questions about this subject, but after long researches I didn't find any that could solve my problem.

I'm trying to display with a label (using tkinter) a variable that I get from the I²C bus. The variable is therefore updated very regularly and automatically. The rest of the window should stay available for the user.

For now, the only way I found to display the label with the updated variable  and to keep the rest of the window available for the user is to do so:

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Gestionnaire de périphériques")
window.minsize(1024,600)

labelValThermo = tk.Label(a_frame_in_the_main_window,text = "")
labelValThermo.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

while True:
    if mcp.get_hot_junction_temperature() != 16.0625:
        labelValThermo.configure(text = "Température thermocouple: {} °C".format(mcp.get_hot_junction_temperature()))
    window.update()
    time.sleep(0.75)
```

The variable that comes from the I²C and got updated is `mcp.get_hot_junction_temperature`

The fact is that I know it's not the best way to force the update in an infinite loop. This should be the role of the `mainloop()`. I found out that the `after()` method could solve my problem but I don't know how to run it. I tried the following code that didn't work:

```
def displayThermoTemp():
    if mcp.get_hot_junction_temperature() != 16.0625:
        labelValThermo.configure(text = "Température thermocouple: {} °C".format(mcp.get_hot_junction_temperature()))
        labelValThermo.after(500,displayThermoTemp)

window = tk.Tk()

labelValThermo = tk.Label(thermoGraphFrame,text = "")

labelValThermo.after(500, displayThermoTemp)

labelValThermo.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

window.mainloop()
```

Does anyone have the right syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How To use `after()` ?**

The `after()` calls the function callback after the given delay in ms. Just define it inside the given function and it'll run just like a while loop till you call `after_cancel(id)` .

**Here is an example:**

```
import tkinter as tk

Count = 1

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text=Count, font = ('', 30))
label.pack()

def update():
    global Count
    Count += 1
    label['text'] = Count

    root.after(100, update)

update()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Update your function with this and call it once before `mainloop()`.

```
def displayThermoTemp():
    if mcp.get_hot_junction_temperature() != 16.0625:
        labelValThermo.configure(text = "Température thermocouple: {} °C".format(mcp.get_hot_junction_temperature()))
        labelValThermo.after(500,displayThermoTemp)

    # 100ms = 0.1 secs
    window(100, displayThermoTemp)
```

Answer (score 2):

**after** has the following syntax:

> after(delay_ms, callback=None, *args)

You need to place the command in your callback function and update the window on which the widget is (in your case the `labelValThermo` looks to be on the `root` window:

```
def displayThermoTemp():
    if mcp.get_hot_junction_temperature() != 16.0625:
        labelValThermo.configure(text = "Température thermocouple: {} °C".format(mcp.get_hot_junction_temperature()))
    root.after(500,displayThermoTemp)
```

Comment: Should the root.after not be outside of the if statement? Otherwise the callback will only be scheduled when the if condition is true.